# Zipkin data not able to persist in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-cloud, zipkin

I am having problem persisting the zipkin data. I did not get any error message. So I am sharing configuration to get a help.

I can see my logs in zipkin UI, but not able to persist in elastic search.

My zipkin-service pom file shared below.

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
                <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-stream</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
                <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-elasticsearch-http</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- add the dependency for elasticsearch via http -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

And my properties looks like this

```
spring:
  profiles: local
  rabbitmq:
    host: ${RABBIT_HOST:localhost}
    username: test
    password: test

  zipkin:
    storage:
    type: elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    jest:
      uris: http://localhost:9200
```

Comment: Elastic search and Rabbitmq is running. I did check elastic search data log i couldnt find anything.